# Verwendung des Wortes „einigten“

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Ich versuche meine Frage auf Deutsch zu stellen, weil ich Deutsch lerne. Bitte korrigieren Sie mich, wenn es Fehler gibt.

Meine Frage ist über das Wort "einigten". Ich habe einen Satz gelesen, der wie folgt lautet:

> Auf einem Krisengipfel in Brüssel einigten sie sich auf Umrisse eines
>   neuen Hilfsprogramms

Was ist der Wortstamm des Wortes "einigten" ?

Was ist die Bedeutung des Wortes "einigten"  in diesem Satz?

Vielen Dank.

Answer (score 4):

*Einigten* ist die Mehrzahl-Vergangenheitsform von *[(sich) einigen](http://dwds.de/?qu=einigen)*. Dies bedeutet *sich einig sein*, *zu einer gemeinsamen Entscheidung kommen*, *einen gemeinsamen Kompromiss finden*, etc.